Error during generation of migrations typescript 5
While running a database migration I do get the following errors:
apps/mtb-api/src/dbconfig_entity/User.ts:11:4 - error TS1240: Unable to resolve signature of property decorator when called as an expression.
  Argument of type 'undefined' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Object'.

11   @PrimaryColumn("varchar", { name: "userId", length: 50, nullable: false })
      ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
apps/mtb-api/src/dbconfig_entity/User.ts:12:3 - error TS2564: Property 'userId' has no initializer and is not definitely assigned in the constructor.

12   userId: string;
     ~~~~~~
apps/mtb-api/src/dbconfig_entity/User.ts:14:4 - error TS1240: Unable to resolve signature of property decorator when called as an expression.
  Argument of type 'undefined' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Object'.

14   @ManyToMany(() => Tenant)
      ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
apps/mtb-api/src/dbconfig_entity/User.ts:15:4 - error TS1240: Unable to resolve signature of property decorator when called as an expression.
  Argument of type 'undefined' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Object'.

15   @JoinTable()
      ~~~~~~~~~~~

Is was trying to generate a migration file for a MySql database.
Actually in code, typeorm is running just fine. The problem is when I use the typeorm cli to generate new migrations, I do receieve errors.
I run the following command:
npm run typeorm -- migration:generate apps/mtb-api/src/db_mirations/dbconfig_migration/new  -d apps/mtb-api/src/db_migrations/mtbConfigDataSource.ts
Here is the tsconfig.json
{
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "rootDir": ".",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "strictPropertyInitialization": false,
    "importHelpers": true,
    "target": "es2015",
    "module": "esnext",
    "lib": ["es2020", "dom"],
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "skipDefaultLibCheck": true,
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "allowUnusedLabels": true,
    "useUnknownInCatchVariables": false,  
    "paths": {
      "@mtb/mtb-core": ["libs/mtb-core/src/index.ts"],
      "@mtb/mtb-requests": ["libs/mtb-requests/src/index.ts"],
      "@mtb/mtb-style": ["libs/mtb-style/src/index.ts"],
      "@mtb/mtb-ui": ["libs/mtb-ui/src/index.ts"],
      "@mtb/svc-IAMAuth0": ["libs/svc-IAMAuth0/src/index.ts"],
      "@mtb/svc-IAMProvider": ["libs/svc-IAMProvider/src/index.ts"]
    }
  },
  "exclude": ["node_modules", "tmp"]
}


The package.json:
{
  "name": "@mtb/source",
  "version": "2.0.0",
  "license": "MIT",
  "scripts": {
    "start:api": "npx nx run mtb-api:serve",
    "start:admin": "npx nx run mtb-admin-app:serve",
    "start:guest": "npx nx run mtb-guest-app-v1:serve",
    "install:guest": "cd apps/guestv1 && npm install --legacy-peer-deps",
    "build api doc": "cd apps/mtb-api && npx tsoa spec",
    "rebuild test environment": "@powershell -NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -Command ./infra/buildtest.ps1",
    "backup_mtb_dev_db": "docker exec -i mtb_development-mysql-1 /usr/bin/mysqldump --all-databases -u root --password=P@ssword1 > ./BackupMtbDev/mtbdevdb.sql",
    "restore_mtb_dev_db": "docker exec -i mtb_development-mysql-1 /usr/bin/mysql -u root --password=P@ssword1 < ./BackupMtbDev/mtbdevdb_noel_30.sql",
    "typeorm": "typeorm-ts-node-commonJs"
  },
  "private": true,
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.14.5",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.14.5",
    "@nx/eslint": "17.1.3",
    "@nx/eslint-plugin": "17.1.3",
    "@nx/express": "^17.1.3",
    "@nx/jest": "17.1.3",
    "@nx/js": "17.2.8",
    "@nx/node": "17.1.3",
    "@nx/react": "17.2.8",
    "@nx/webpack": "17.1.3",
    "@nx/workspace": "17.1.3",
    "@pmmmwh/react-refresh-webpack-plugin": "^0.5.7",
    "@svgr/webpack": "^8.0.1",
    "@swc-node/register": "~1.6.7",
    "@swc/cli": "~0.1.62",
    "@swc/core": "~1.3.85",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^6.4.1",
    "@testing-library/react": "^14.2.1",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^14.5.2",
    "@types/bcryptjs": "^2.4.6",
    "@types/cookie-parser": "^1.4.6",
    "@types/cors": "^2.8.17",
    "@types/express": "4.17.13",
    "@types/geojson": "^7946.0.13",
    "@types/jest": "^29.5.11",
    "@types/jsonwebtoken": "^9.0.5",
    "@types/leaflet": "^1.9.8",
    "@types/lodash": "^4.14.202",
    "@types/multer": "^1.4.11",
    "@types/multer-s3": "^3.0.3",
    "@types/node": "18.14.2",
    "@types/react": "18.2.33",
    "@types/react-dom": "18.2.14",
    "@types/react-world-flags": "^1.4.5",
    "@types/supertest": "^6.0.1",
    "@types/swagger-ui-express": "^4.1.6",
    "@types/uuid": "^9.0.7",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^6.9.1",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^6.9.1",
    "babel-jest": "^29.4.1",
    "eslint": "~8.46.0",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "^9.0.0",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "2.27.5",
    "eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "6.7.1",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "7.32.2",
    "eslint-plugin-react-hooks": "4.6.0",
    "jest": "^29.7.0",
    "jest-environment-jsdom": "^29.4.1",
    "jest-environment-node": "^29.4.1",
    "nx": "17.1.3",
    "prettier": "^2.6.2",
    "react-refresh": "^0.10.0",
    "supertest": "^6.3.3",
    "ts-jest": "^29.1.1",
    "ts-node": "10.9.1",
    "typescript": "~5.5.4",
    "url-loader": "^4.1.1"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@auth0/auth0-react": "^2.2.4",
    "@aws-sdk/client-s3": "^3.465.0",
    "@chakra-ui/icons": "^2.1.1",
    "@chakra-ui/react": "^2.8.2",
    "@emotion/react": "^11.11.4",
    "@emotion/styled": "^11.11.5",
    "@swc/helpers": "~0.5.2",
    "axios": "^1.0.0",
    "bcryptjs": "^2.4.3",
    "chakra-react-select": "^4.7.6",
    "class-validator": "^0.14.0",
    "cookie-parser": "^1.4.6",
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "date-fns": "^2.30.0",
    "dotenv": "^16.3.1",
    "express": "^4.18.1",
    "express-oauth2-jwt-bearer": "^1.6.0",
    "express-validator": "^7.0.1",
    "geojson": "^0.5.0",
    "i18next-browser-languagedetector": "^7.2.0",
    "jsonwebtoken": "^9.0.2",
    "leaflet": "^1.9.4",
    "lodash": "^4.17.21",
    "multer": "^1.4.5-lts.1",
    "multer-s3": "^3.0.1",
    "mysql2": "^3.6.5",
    "react": "18.2.0",
    "react-cookie": "^7.0.2",
    "react-cropper": "^2.3.3",
    "react-dom": "18.2.0",
    "react-drag-drop-files": "^2.3.10",
    "react-hook-form": "^7.50.0",
    "react-i18next": "^14.0.1",
    "react-icons": "^5.0.1",
    "react-leaflet": "4.2.1",
    "react-player": "^2.14.1",
    "react-quill": "^2.0.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^6.22.0",
    "react-select": "^5.8.0",
    "react-world-flags": "^1.6.0",
    "reflect-metadata": "^0.2.2",
    "sharp": "^0.33.0",
    "swagger-ui-express": "^5.0.0",
    "tslib": "^2.3.0",
    "tsoa": "^5.1.1",
    "typeorm": "^0.3.20",
    "uuid": "^9.0.1",
    "winston": "^3.11.0",
    "winston-daily-rotate-file": "^4.7.1",
    "wkx": "^0.5.0"
  }
}


This typescript file contains the datasource info:
import { DataSource } from "typeorm";

export const mtbConfigDataSource = new DataSource({
  name: "MTBConfig",
  type: "mysql",
  host: "127.0.0.1",
  port: 3310,
  database: "mtb_config_clean",
  username: "MTB_Super_Admin",
  password: "P@ssword1",
  synchronize: false,
  logging: false,
  entities: ["apps/mtb-api/src/dbconfig_entity/**/*.ts"],
  migrations: ["apps/mtb-api/src/db_migrations/dbconfig_migration/**/*.ts}"],
  legacySpatialSupport: false,
});


